# I cannot install any package (linux-image-server, linux-server dependencies errors)

Tags: 12.04, dependencies

I'm very new to Ubuntu and I messed up something and I cannot install any packages with apt-get install.

Initially I got this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.36.43) but 3.2.0.37.45 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And when I tried to run "sudo apt-get -f install" I get this:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-server:
 linux-image-server depends on linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.36.43); however:
  Package linux-image-server is not configured yet.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.36.43); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.37.45.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-server
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help is much appreciated because I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Related: [APT wedged by kernel version mismatch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253243/apt-wedged-by-kernel-version-mismatch)

Answer (score 14):

The way I fixed this was to manually install a newer version of the `linux-server` package as such:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/linux-server_3.2.0.37.45_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-server_3.2.0.37.45_amd64.deb
```

If you're running a 32-bit system you'll need a slightly different URL and package name that you can find [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta).

Thanks to @Eliah Kagan for his answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/253581/79271 and help with question-meta-issues.

Comment: This is really helpful! And I follow your idea fix my linux-headers-server and linux-image-server missing problem.

Comment: I've had to do this a couple of times now. Thank goodness for the voting system, to know where I've been and what worked :D