# 12.04-server update failure after full /boot, apt not working, unmet dependencies to non exiting linux-image kernel

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, apt, kernel

Unattended upgrade failed after full /boot partition. Creating disk-space by deleting old kernels with the recommended command

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x-x-generic
```

does not work and gives the following reason:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.38.46) but 3.2.0.40.48 is to be installed
```

(I created space on /boot by rm old kernel images)

All suggestions and solutions offered on the questions 
[APT wedged by kernel version mismatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253243/apt-wedged-by-kernel-version-mismatch) and
https://askubuntu.com/questions/166622/error-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-while-running-sudo-ap?rq=1
do not work, giving the same unmet dependencies.

```
server:~$ uname -r
3.2.0-40-generic
```

So kernel is version 40.

```
server:~$ sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
||/ Name                 Version              Description
+++-====================-============================================================================
un  linux-image          <none>               (no description available)
un  linux-image-3.0      <none>               (no description available)
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-23 3.2.0-23.36          Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-36 3.2.0-36.57          Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-37 3.2.0-37.58          Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
un  linux-image-3.2.0-38 <none>               (no description available)
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-40 3.2.0-40.64          Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic  3.2.0.38.46          Generic Linux kernel image
iU  linux-image-server   3.2.0.38.46          Linux kernel image on Server Equipment.
```

kernel 38 is missing, but last two images refer to version 38

```
server:~$ sudo apt-cache policy linux-server
linux-server:
  Installed: 3.2.0.38.46
  Candidate: 3.2.0.40.48
  Version table:
     3.2.0.40.48 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.2.0.38.46 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.0.23.25 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Now I'm confused. 
booting into an older kernel 37 gives the same unmet depedencies.
Trying in a desperate attempt to force the install of the 38 kernel fails:

```
server:~$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite linux-image-generic_3.2.0.38.46_amd64.deb
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic; however:
      Package linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic is not installed.
```

Using aptitude gives the same problems: although it tries to up/downgrade several packages to resolve the unmet dependencies.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to you. I ended using `dpkg` to remove both `linux-server` and `linux-image-server`

I tried to download the older versions but they were not in the normal apt-get repositories as they had been replaced by newer versions already.

Once I did that, I was able to reinstall the correct versions via `apt-get`

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to delete older kernels via `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo dpkg -r
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Ryan! Not all of us are regex gods =D; can you please explain what this command exactly does? Does it delete everything but the running kernel? Or does it leave the previous latest kernel?