# Boot partition full, failed upgrade prevents cleaning

Tags: boot, upgrade, dependencies

This seems to be a common problem area from all the other questions and answers but none of them seem to address my specific problem.

After several upgrades my server boot partition filled up. Apparently the system continued to try to upgrade and is now in some sort of vicious circle. I can't upgrade because of an unmatched dependency and I can't clean because of a pending upgrade.

I manually removed several old files to provide space, following suggestions in other answered questions (listed versions and rm'ed five oldest) but the problem persists. Here's what happens if I try to fix the install:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
Correcting dependencies... Done  
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
  linux-image-3.2.0-60-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-65-generic  
  linux-image-3.2.0-63-generic linux-image-3.2.0-58-generic  
  linux-headers-3.2.0-60 linux-headers-3.2.0-61 linux-headers-3.2.0-63  
  linux-headers-3.2.0-58 linux-headers-3.2.0-64 linux-headers-3.2.0-59 
  linux-headers-3.2.0-65 linux-headers-3.2.0-60-generic  
  linux-headers-3.2.0-63-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-58-generic  
  linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic linux-image-3.2.0-64-generic  
  linux-image-3.2.0-59-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-61-generic  
  linux-headers-3.2.0-64-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-59-generic  
  linux-image-3.2.0-65-generic  
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.  
The following extra packages will be installed:  
  linux-server  
The following packages will be upgraded:  
  linux-server  
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 158 not upgraded.  
1 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/1,736 B of archives.  
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.  
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y  
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:  
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.68.81); however:  
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.74.88.  
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.68.81); however:  
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.74.88.  
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):  
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured  
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a     previous failure.
                        Errors were encountered while processing:  
 linux-server  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

You'll see I've tried this before...
Tried `autoremove`, `clean`, `autoclean`, `configure`.

If it is any sort of a clue, about half the time when I run that command I lose the terminal session!

```
$ df -h /boot  
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sda1       228M  107M  109M  50% /boot
```

and all operations involving `apt-get` or `dpkg` fail with an error similar to the above.

Comment: Show us (in your question) the output of `df -h`. Did you try to remove the kernel-images with `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.2.0-60-generic linux-image-3.2.0-63-generic linux-image-3.2.0-58-generic linux-image-3.2.0-59-generic` ?

Comment: Edited post. An update normally uses around 14% of /boot so 50% free should be OK. As per edit, nothing involving apt-get works, it just fails and tells me to run install, which then fails as above.

Comment: OP says the question is similar in an _answer_. Voting as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer in this similar question: [APT wedged by kernel version mismatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253243/apt-wedged-by-kernel-version-mismatch)

I manually installed linux-server 3.2.0.74.88 as shown in the answer to that question and everything was sorted. Many thanks to Eliah Kagan for a thoughtful, useful and comprehensive answer.