# Can't Boot From DVD or USB Stick after Boot-Repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dW45nTKbZq/

I have a dual boot with Windows 10.  I was unable to boot Ubuntu from disk.  I have a bootable USB stick and that worked.  I booted from the USB and then booted a recovery Ubuntu option in Grub.  Then, I was able to get into my Ubuntu partition.  I was updating my system when the machine just shut down.  After which, I ran Boot-Repair.

Now, I can boot from my Ubuntu partition, but once I enter my password, the screen is all messed up and I can not Login.  It doesn't seem to recognize my password.  Also, now, I can not boot from my USB Ubuntu Stick.  I made a brand new Ubuntu ISO image and that will not boot either.  (A reinstall previously fixed the screen problem.)

I have tried changing the boot order in the BIOS.  That does not help.

The link to the Boot-Repair log is above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any abnormal shutdown corrupts system. You need to run fsck on any ext4 partitions and may need chkdsk on NTFS partitions from a Windows repair disk. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789  And then if in middle of updates you need to boot recovery mode and finish updates or chroot into system to finish updates. https://askubuntu.com/questions/253243/apt-wedged-by-kernel-version-mismatch

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain what happened exactly.  I was studying my machines operation and at one point, while trying to login, I got the same messed up screen but, after a while I did get into my machine.  The icons (like the wifi icon) were blanked out and I could not access my Windows drive but, I was able to run an update.  After the update, the system seems to be working fine; I can boot from my USB stick and; access my Windows drive from my Linux partition.  But, I still cannot boot Ubuntu from my DVD.